# set wallpaper in android in my app

Tags: android

I wanted to get a picture from my link in the program and show it in the app, and after clicking on a button, I set up a photo that was downloaded from the link on the background.
Thank you for answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

add this in manifst

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

and in class

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
    myWallpaperManager.setImageResource(R.raw.my_photo);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```